# How to add service.AddDbContext in class library .NET CORE

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core-2.0

I have a class library alone in a solution. This library will be published as a NuGet package.

So, I want to add the library to my project and I have to connect startup of the project to define this:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>     
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:LocalConnectionString"]));
```

But there is no startup in my class library project. How can I define this in the library project for my actual projects ?

Comment: Expose an extension method that would allow access to your configuration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let your library expose an extension point to be able to integrate with other libraries that want to configure your library.

```
public static class MyExtensionPoint {
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyLibraryDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration) {
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:LocalConnectionString"]));
        return services;
    }
}
```

That way in the main `Startup` you can now add your library services via the extension.

```
public class Startup {

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        //...

        services.AddMyLibraryDbContext(Configuration);

        services.AddMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: A small reminder : There have to be install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` to use `options.UseSqlServer` extension in dependency injection.

Comment: @ŞerefCanMuştu that would be correct. If you do not want to tie/couple the library to it you can expose the config function instead so that the startup will manage that.